# What makes LM386 so common at sound amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, speakers, power-amplifier

TL, DR at the end.

Preamble: This quesiton results from an analog electronics lab project. However, I am not someone who asks here and wants you to do the job for me. Rather, I have been extensively spending time for this and right now I feel I am stuck. So I wanted to ask for your recommendations

I have been dealing with constructing an audio amplifier for few days. I need this for a project at university. So **I CANNOT USE LM386**, instead I have to design my amplifier circuit using basic components of electronics(res,cap,bjt,mosfet etc.).

However, while searching on the internet, I saw that LM386 is a very commonly used IC for audio amplification projects. I assume that LM386 is an opAmp in its basics. But I don't know what makes it this much different than other opAmps (such has LM741, another widely used opAmp). So this is the deal, I want to learn which feature of it makes the difference.

My thought:

Since an 8 ohms speaker will be driven at the output, I think it might be the output impedance of LM386 is so low to be able to drive a load as low as 8 ohms speaker. And indeed, when I investigate the LM386 datasheet, in the example applications part, they used speaker symbol as load and the recommended load value is 4 - 32 ohms, which made me to think that they designed LM386 specifically to drive low resistive loads. However, I couldn't find the output impedance value at anywhere in the datasheet for LM386 ( which I also could not find for LM741 an I totaly don't know **why they don't include it** (?)).

**So, question #1** : Is LM386 specially produced to drive speakers, or its capability of doing that is because it is designed to drive low resistance value loads like a speaker?

When I was doing some simulations where an LM741 was used and the 8 ohms load directly connected to its output, the voltage on the 8 ohms load can never exceed 160mV peak levels. And my idea is this happens because of the fact that LM741 has a maximum output current of 20-25 mA.

**So, question #2: if I am right and this is the case, can I conclude that LM386 is engineered so that it also will be able to deliver high amount of currents to the load?** ( I think that way because for an 8 ohms speaker, 2 W of power ( I guess a normal power rating for a small speaker) will occur at 500 mA, and 0.5 A is much higher than the rating for LM741(25mA) )

In a nutshell, I think you might be understand the situation. I am actualy trying to understand the key factors which make LM386 a better audio application opAmp than LM741(for example). My aim is to understand these and by that, to design my own topologies.

**TL, DR:** The origin of all these questions in my brain is -> With what kind of an approach, I might be able to drive an 8 ohms speaker effectively at 1-2 W power ratings without using LM386 or the commercial ICs like it.

By the way, I am also open to the advices or recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the *fifth* question you've asked about this project in the past two days.  **You are not using this site correctly**, and you are seemingly not following the path which students in your course are expected to follow, either.

Comment: The LM386 is not an opamp.  It is a power amplifier.  It not an especially good power amplifier.  Its only advantages are that it is cheap, it is available everywhere, and circuit diagrams for it are available all over the internet and in books and magazines.

Comment: @ChrisStratton let me tell you the path the other students are following: open google, type audio amplifier circuit diagram, do the same. I am just trying to get some insight.

Comment: Reading the list of features, list of applications and description on the first page of the LM386 and LM741 data sheets will answer your questions about their differences and what they are designed to do.

Comment: The LM386 isn't a **good** audio amplifier.  It's a **popular DIY** audio amplifier.  There's a lot of stuff circulating around the DIY electronics space that's just rehashed ideas from decades ago using parts that are considered "common".  The LM386 is one of those parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, LM386 is designed to supply far **more current** than most op-amps.

However, LM386 **should not be viewed as an op-amp**. It is designed to drive low-resistance loads like a speaker, while op-amps have far more applications. LM386 *does* have differential inputs (inverting and non-inverting). And it *does* have a single output, like an op amp. But its internal biasing is different from an op-amp. It is designed to set quiescent output voltage mid-way between the supply voltage.
Most often, you'll see LM386 circuits with a single uni-polar supply less than +12V. With a +12V supply, output voltage is very close to +6V DC.

Those differential input pins on LM386 have internal pull-down resistors to the negative supply pin, unlike most op-amps that have open-circuit inputs. With inputs left open-circuit, **+in** and **-in** sit very close to the negative supply voltage (usually ground) on a LM386. Done like this, output voltage sits near half-DCsupply.

In summary:

- LM386 has low gain between 20 to 200. Op-amp has much higher gain at DC
- LM386 self-biases inputs and outputs. Op-amp must be biased by user.
- LM386 has much more current available at output. Op-amps generally limit current to +-20mA

Duplicating LM386 with discrete transistors, resistors, capacitors is not a good way to proceed - it is very difficult to match current gain of discrete transistors, and it is very difficult to temperature-track each transistor in the same way that LM386 transistors track on one silicon chip.

Comment: thanks!, it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The LM386 is not suitable to your task due to the small chip size and insufficient output power into 8 Ohms at rated temperature rise.

However there is nothing wrong with the configuration of the output stage to be used with power discrete transistors inside a feedback loop with an Op Amp.

Take care to bias input and output to get Vout ~ Vs/2

[image]

However a good Audio Amp in a small SMD chip for $0.5 uses differential outputs so there is no need for a large DC blocking cap on a single supply. Also the output drivers use inexpensive push-pull FETs using NFB gain to  reduce the distortion.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I don't want to use LM386 already. But didn't understand the "chip size" part. Also the at the 3rd example of output power section, the TYP value of 100 is a typing error and it is probably 1000, right?

Comment: right............. at 32 Ohms and 16V  . I show the better IC's so you understand how to learn from the better examples,, Then attempt a discrete version  but my previous answer will work.... complementary PNP,NPN

Comment: thanks for the effort